# Selenium wait for element to appear and dissapear

Tags: selenium, wait

I have the following element:

```
<div class="ui-helper-hidden" id="shell.indicator.busy">
  <label>Processing...</label>
  <br />
  <img src="/RightCrowd/Images/loading.gif" alt="" />
</div>
```

And it appears like this:

[image: Processing]

I would like to wait for it to appear and then to disappear and continue with accessing elements. This appears on most pages of the web application. We've tried a few things but sometimes it is visible by Selenium and sometimes is not, although I can see it with my eyes.

I believe that this processing image appears on top of the current page and using the current handler may be useless. Not sure.

We've tried something like this:

```
        WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10))
                   .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'/Images/loading.gif')]")));

        boolean processingEnd = (new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutWaitForProgressbar))
                   .until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("shell.indicator.busy")));
```

So we've tried both xpath and id... Please let me know what's the best way to handle this situation.

Comment: What happens when you tried it with xpath a nd with id? Did it throw an exception? Which exception?

Comment: It's a TimeoutException. The code has try catches but I did not copy paste everything. I'm interested to detect correctly when it's there and to detect when it has disappeared.

Comment: Is the timeout on waiting for it to appear, or waiting for it to disappear? If you bump up the timeout, does it eventually find it?

Comment: It times out when waiting for it to appear. However, the timeout is 10 seconds and I can visually see it for 10 seconds..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the `WebDriverWait` would check the Expected Condition status every half a second. I would try to issue the expected condition check requests more often with a [`FluentWait`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html) class:

```
Wait wait = new FluentWait(driver)
   .withTimeout(timeoutWaitForProgressbar, SECONDS)
   .pollingEvery(100, MILLISECONDS);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("shell.indicator.busy")));
```

Comment: As a comment, the pollingEvery does not accept double values, but I can use Milliseconds.  Still not working. I will wait for others to reply...

Comment: It's more stable now. I used xpath (e.g. By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'/Images/loading.gif')]"))  instead of id and it seems more consistent now.

Comment: @YahyaHHussein what do you mean by not working? it worked for the OP long ago by the way.

Comment: https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html

Comment: @YahyaHHussein ah, we just need to make the answer up-to-date. Thanks for pointing that out.